# Pre-fill stdin for a process in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I want a process to keep reading inputs from stdin after sending a string to it initially. How can i do it in bash?

here is a incorrect solution to explain what i am trying to do.

```
echo "$HEADER" | cat - < /dev/stdin
```

Here cat command must receive the content of `$HEADER` first then behave like how `cat -` should behave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pipe multiple commands in sequence, where the the first writes a header and the second is just `cat` to relay input from stdin to stdout:

```
{ echo "$HEADER"; cat; } | yourcommand
```

The problem with your approach is that you can only ever have one stdin, while you try to use two.  `echo "foo" | cat /dev/stdin /dev/tty` could have been an option, but this unnecessarily relies on having a terminal.